# Filter Outlook appointments by category

Tags: c#, internationalization, outlook, outlook-2010, mapi

I have written this code to find the total duration of all appointments of a specified category within a specified time range:

```cs
private readonly MAPIFolder _timing;

private int CalculateTotalDuration(DateTime start, DateTime end, string category)
{
    string filter = String.Format(
        "([Start] >= '{0:g}') AND ([End] <= '{1:g}') AND ([Categories] = '{2}')",
        start, end, category);
    return _timing.Items.Restrict(filter).Cast<AppointmentItem>().
        Sum(appt => appt.Duration);
}
```

This code results in the following exception when used with Russian version of Outlook (I did not test it with English version though):

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  Message=Условие неверно.
  Source=Microsoft Outlook
  ErrorCode=-2147352567
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Items.Restrict(String Filter)
       ...
```

When I replace `[Categories]` with `[Категории]`, i.e.

```cs
string filter = String.Format(
    "([Start] >= '{0:g}') AND ([End] <= '{1:g}') AND ([Категории] = '{2}')",
    start, end, category);
```

it works with Russian version of Outlook. But obviously it will not work with other languages.

How to filter Outlook appointments by category in a multilanguage way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use a SQL query (*prefix the query with "@SQL="*) and use the DASL name for the Categories - `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/Keywords/0x0000101F` or `urn:schemas:mailheader:keywords`.

Answer (score 6):

I have come up with the following DASL filter that works for me:

```cs
var filter = String.Format(
    "@SQL=(\"urn:schemas:calendar:dtstart\" >= '{0:g}' " +
    "AND \"urn:schemas:calendar:dtend\" <= '{1:g}' " +
    "AND \"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Keywords\" LIKE '%{2}%')",
    start, end, category);
```

Actually I have built it using the DASL query builder:

[image: QueryBuilder]

To display a Query Builder tab I have created **QueryBuilder** key in **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software \Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook** as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc513841%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Thanks to [Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/332059/dmitry-streblechenko) who suggested to use DASL.