# Show Outlook calendar with only selected category

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar, categories

Is it in any way possible to get Outlook to show a monthly calendar only showing appointments of a selected category.

I can export the calendar to a table and the show the item in a calendar using some Delphi code, but it would be nicer to do it directly in Outlook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a good start :

```
Sub ConfigureDayViewFonts()
    Dim objView As CalendarView
    Dim CriteRia As String
    Dim SearchedCategory As String

    SearchedCategory = "SearchedCategory"

    CriteRia = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) _
        & "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Keywords" _
        & Chr(34) & " ci_startswith '" & SearchedCategory & "'"

    ' Check if the current view is a calendar view.
    If Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView.ViewType = _
        olCalendarView Then

        ' Obtain a CalendarView object reference for the
        ' current calendar view.
        Set objView = _
            Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView

        With objView
            ' Set the calendar view to show a
            ' single day.
            .CalendarViewMode = olCalendarViewMonth
            .Filter = CriteRia

            ' Save the calendar view.
            '.Save
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

See this answer and its suggestion do adjust the filter yourself : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14152882/4628637

Comment: thanks for input - that helped me in the right direction as to setup a filter that show the entries I want and then print it.